# Android simple adapter display in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview

here is what I have.

```
public class Contact {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String homeNumber;
    private String workNumber;
    private String homeAddress;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String workAddress;
    private String notes;
    private int contactNumber;

    //A constructor and a bunch of getters and setters that are unimportant

}
```

I have this statement: `public static ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();` in a class named `NewContact`.

This is my adapter code in my main android java class.

```
ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, 
                R.layout.home_screen_contacts_view, NewContact.contactList);
```

The problem is as follows, I want the list view to just show the First and Last name of the contact but at the moment it is showing the package name and stuff because it is a contact adapter rather than a string adapter.

This is what it looks like when I add a contact.

[image]

My question is, how can I use the contact class getters to display just the first name and last name when i make a contact?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I have not called setters but the  class variables are set in the constructor.

```
NewContact.contactList.add(new Contact(firstName.getText().toString(),
                        lastName.getText().toString(),mobileNumber.getText().toString(),
                        homeNumber.getText().toString(),workNumber.getText().toString(),
                        homeAddress.getText().toString(),emailAddress.getText().toString(),
                        workAddress.getText().toString(),contactNotes.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: post your View getView() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `toString()` method in the `Contact` class so as it would return a concatination of `firstName` and `lastName`.

Comment: It's printing null, but I think this is getting closer to the answer though. Its just saying null null. Im writing `return firstname + " " + lastname;`

Comment: @Clay well that means objects `firstName` and `secondName` are not initialized or initialized with `null`. Review your object creation method.

Comment: I dont really know how I'm supposed to change them. They're just class variables that belong to the contact class, as in, every contact has a name, number, address etc

Comment: @Clay it looks like you didn't call setters for the object - that is what I meant

Comment: @Maxin Efimov Do I call the setters inside the toString() method? I'm sorry if this sounds stupid, I'm a beginner at Android I just started.

Comment: @Clay No. I mean that the object of class `Contact` you are displaying via the `Adapter` is not initialized. That means you crated it with probably `new Contact()` but did not called `setFirstName` etc. Thus in the `toString` method all the variables are `null`;

Comment: @Clay that's a wierd behaviour. Probably there is a trouble inside constructor or you are reinitializing the list or something like this. Try to debug it by yourself, as I said the problem is: in the object of class `Contact` two fields are `null`s, try to find why. Just do step-by-step investigation. Good luck!

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked this... I'm so stupid. You were right, the problem **was** in the constructor. I wrote `firstName = this.firstName` instead of `this.firstName = firstName`. It's working now, thanks alot for your comments they helped me out a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Adapter by extending BaseAdapter. Then in your custom Adapter override the getView() method. In this method you can access various fields of Contacts class, and set accordingly.
Please google for ListView custom adapter