# Android: toString() method not working properly with custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview

I had an adapting a listview. The contents of the list view were objects from my class `People`. The `People` class had Names and ages. I wanted to configure how the people were displayed so I constructed my `toString()` method as follows:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        switch(HomeScreenActivity.displayMode){
        case 1:
            return lastName + " " + firstName;
        case 2:
            return firstName + " " + mobileNumber;
        case 3:
            return lastName + " " + mobileNumber;
        default:
            return firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
    }
```

So how this works is that, in my program, the user is asked for his/her preferred display method, they select it and `myDisplaySwitcher` changes accordingly so the `toString()` method causes the listview to display its contents differently.

As soon as I implemented my custom adapter, this stopped working. I looked into the matter and I found that my database of people WERE being updated but the listview just was not refreshing its view eventhough I was invalidating views and notifyingdatasetchanged etc etc. Is there something I'm missing about custom adapters?

Thanks

EDIT: Please see my EXACT `toString()` method. It's not working with this method. It worked with the normal adapter but not my custom adapter.

EDIT2: Here is my customAdapter. This is most likely where the problem is but it's all very confusing for me.

```
private class peopleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<People> mData;

        public peopleAdapter(List<People> data) {
            mData = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position).getFullName();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView result;

            if (convertView == null) {
                result = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.home_screen_people_view, parent, false);
                //result.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                        //R.color.darkish_blue));
            } else {
                result = (TextView) convertView;
            }

            final String personRow = getItem(position);
            result.setText(personRow);
            result.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);

            return result;
        }

    }
```

EDIT3: This was a previous question by me. I followed the accepted answer and it worked. This was for a simple ArrayAdapter that is already implemented. Now I'm trying to achieve the same thing except with a custom adapter. [Android simple adapter display in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843245/android-simple-adapter-display-in-a-listview)

Comment: Even if it doesn't fix the problem, you should add the `@Override` annotation to the function.

Comment: @Override
public void toString(){
}

Comment: Added code is not the overridden toString. toString must return the string. but ino your code this does not.

Comment: have you checked your mData.get(position).getFullName(); is returning correct string to set on textview.

Comment: Actually ArrayAdapter also uses getItem internally. What happens inside is it gets your object using getItem converts it into string and displays. Same thing you are also doing. Should I update my answer ?

Comment: @BharatSharma put an answer so I can upvote it and select it as the correct answer

Comment: @BharatSharma I have updated it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using listview then you need to call **custom_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** to refresh listview. It will automatically update the listview. Real thing is whatever string your listview is dipalying should be correct in **custom_adapter** according to the user choice.

If it is also not solving you problem then check your mData.get(position).getFullName(); is returning correct string to set on textview.

Answer (score 1):

As you are overriding the toString() then your code should look like this:

```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
        switch(myDisplaySwitcher){
        case 1: return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + age ;
                break; 
        case 2: return lastName + " " + firstName + " " + age ;
                break;
        case 3: return firstName + " " + lastName ;
                break;
        }
    }
```

As you are not returning the string in your code your listView content is not updating accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

- adding the `@Override` annotation to your method
- returning a `String` for each logical pathway, which implies
- adding a `default` statement to the `switch`
- check `myDisplaySwitcher` for `null` before the `switch` if it's a `Character`, `Byte`, `Integer`, or `Short` (that is, not a primitive)

Comment: I agree with adding `@Override` and the `default` statement, but why wouldn't it compile? This is assuming that all the variables are global.

Comment: @musical_coder the method must return a `String`. The code you displayed does not.

Comment: My mistake, `toString()` should definitely return a String :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void toString() {
    switch(myDisplaySwitcher){
    case 1: System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + age);
            break;
    case 2: System.out.println(lastName + " " + firstName + " " + age);
            break;
    case 3: System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
            break;
    }
}
```

Default `toString();` has been overridden and your method will be invoked when `toString()` is called.It is recommended that you rename your method to something like `convertToString()` as a good coding practice.